# With Ember Data, finding an actual record (not just a promise)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm creating a record with a polymorphic belongsTo relationship. Its creation looks something like this:

```
this.get('store').createRecord('membership', { member: @get('session.currentUser') })
```

This throws the error:

```
You can only add a 'amorphous' record to this relationship
```

The User model does inherit from Amorphous, however. So I'm assuming the problem here is that I'm passing in a promise, rather than an actual model. Is there a way to get the resolved model before passing it in? Something like:

```
this.get('store').createRecord('membership', { member: @get('session.currentUser').
  then( function(user) {
    return user;
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. (It still passes the promise, not the resolved model.) But surely there's some way to force Ember Model to give you the resolved model?

Comment: Sounds like a job for ECMAScript 6 [Generators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch it around like this:

```
@get('session.currentUser').then( function(user) {
    this.get('store').createRecord('membership', { member: user })
})
```